# I try to debug the HoverCraft class, it's make me anger for hour

Tags: python, debugging, inheritance

I have this lab on my school and it take me long to finish it. HoverCraft is child of both LandVehicle and SeaVessel. I use same method as other but it doesn't work.

```
class Vehicle:
  def __init__(self,name,maxPassengers,maxSpeed):
    self.name=name
    self.maxPassengers=maxPassengers
    self.maxSpeed=maxSpeed
  def display(self):   
    print('Ten phuong tien:',self.name)
    print('So hanh khach toi da:',self.maxPassengers)
    print('Toc do toi da:',self.maxSpeed)

class LandVehicle(Vehicle):
  def __init__(self,name,maxPassengers,maxSpeed,numWheels,drive):
    super().__init__(name,maxPassengers,maxSpeed)
    self.numWheels=numWheels
    self.drive=drive
  def display(self):   
    print('\nTen phuong tien:',self.name)
    print('So hanh khach toi da:',self.maxPassengers)
    print('Toc do toi da:',self.maxSpeed)
    print('Banh xe:',self.numWheels)
    print('Ghe lai:',self.drive)

class SeaVessel(Vehicle):
  def __init__(self,name,maxPassengers,maxSpeed,displacement,launch):
    super().__init__(name,maxPassengers,maxSpeed)
    self.displacemant=displacement
    self.launch=launch
  def display(self):    
    print('\nTen phuong tien:',self.name)
    print('So hanh khach toi da:',self.maxPassengers)
    print('Toc do toi da:',self.maxSpeed)
    print('Trong luong:',self.displacemant)
    print('Xuat diem:',self.launch)

class HoverCraft(LandVehicle,SeaVessel): #My main problem
  def __init__(self, name, maxPassengers, maxSpeed, numWheels, drive,displacement,launch,enterLand,enterSea):
    LandVehicle.__init__(self,name,maxPassengers,maxSpeed,numWheels,drive)
    SeaVessel.__init__(self,name,maxPassengers,maxSpeed,displacement,launch)
    self.enterLand=enterLand
    self.enterSea=enterSea
  def display(self):
    super().display()    
    print('Banh xe:',self.numWheels)
    print('Ghe lai:',self.drive)
    print('Trong luong:',self.displacemant)
    print('Xuat diem:',self.launch)
    print('Vao dat:',self.enterLand)
    print('Vao bien:',self.enterSea)
 
v=Vehicle('xe',4,'40km/h')
v1=LandVehicle('xe tai',2,'60km/h',4,1)
v3=SeaVessel('tau danh ca',50,'22knot',20,"3h")
v5=HoverCraft('moto nuoc',2,'80km/h',0,1,10,'2h','6h','17h')
v.display()
v1.display()
v3.display()
v5.display()
```

It keep getting wrong and told that i got error in LandVehicle class and Sea Vessel class, it said i missing required position. I tried to use `super()` or `super()display()` and still not working.
Here is full error traceback

```
 File "/home/runner/inheritance2/main.py", line 79, in <module>
    v5=HoverCraft('moto nuoc',2,'80km/h',0,1,10,'2h','6h','17h')
  File "/home/runner/inheritance2/main.py", line 61, in __init__
    LandVehicle.__init__(self,name,maxPassengers,maxSpeed,numWheels,drive)
  File "/home/runner/inheritance2/main.py", line 13, in __init__
    super().__init__(name,maxPassengers,maxSpeed)
TypeError: SeaVessel.__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'displacement' and 'launch'
```

Comment: " it said i missing required position." - Please always include the full error traceback corresponding to this exact version of the code in your question, not some vague description of the error that is useless to us.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `super().some_method()` does not always call a method on the (or a) superclass. Instead calls the method on the next type in the [method resolution order](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-method-resolution-order) (MRO).

The method resolution order for your `HoverCraft` class is `HoverCraft`, `LandVehicle`, `SeaVessel`, `Vehicle`, `object`. In particular, after `LandVehicle` is `SeaVessel`, so when creating a `Hovercraft` instance, a call to `super().__init__(...)` within `LandVehicle.__init__` will call `SeaVessel.__init__`, not `Vehicle.__init__`, as you might expect.

So, how can you fix this? One way is to modify `LandVehicle.__init__` to always call `Vehicle.__init__`, by replacing the line

```py
super().__init__(name,maxPassengers,maxSpeed)
```

with

```py
Vehicle.__init__(self,name,maxPassengers,maxSpeed)
```

Another way is to force Python to use the method-resolution order of the `LandVehicle` class. To do this, replace the line with

```py
super().__init__(name,maxPassengers,maxSpeed)
```

with

```py
super(LandVehicle, LandVehicle).__init__(self,name,maxPassengers,maxSpeed)
```

The second argument to the call to `super` here is what tells Python to use the `LandVehicle` class's MRO. The first one tells Python to start after the type `LandVehicle` in this MRO.